# TTPhotoViewController ignores image orientation (mirror)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I have a problem I am using `three20` in my project and I am Using `TTThumbnailViewController` and `TTPhotoViewController` and I am loading bunch of photos and bunch of them is just mirror copy of the ones already loaded. (I just change the UIImageOrientation after loading the data from disk)

In `ThumbViewControleller` everything works fine! and as expected But in the `TTPhotoViewController` I see both image in original orientation and I debugged it and centerphotoView has right Orientation but still shows in original orientation I spent llike 6 hours on it and I am desperate could you please help me what to set or what to fix ?